# Postgres generic function to sum up json values

Tags: json, regex, postgresql

I am working on a function to sum up survey scores and am trying to make it dynamic so I don't have to hardcode the number of questions for each survey in the function.  The answers are stored as text in JSON format.  At this point I am looping through the records in the DB and I figured I would replace all the keys that start out in the form of q1, q2, q3, ... and replace them with q so I can extract all the values

```
temp_answers := regexp_replace(row.answers, 'q[0-9]*', 'q', 'g');
```

BEFORE:

```
{
  "q5": {
    "text": "StronglyAgree",
    "score": "4"
  },
  "q2": {
    "text": "StronglyAgree",
    "score": "4"
  },
  "q1": {
    "text": "StronglyAgree",
    "score": "4"
  },
  "q4": {
    "text": "StronglyAgree",
    "score": "4"
  },
  "q3": {
    "text": "StronglyAgree",
    "score": "4"
  }
}
```

AFTER:

```
{
  "q": {
      "text": "StronglyAgree",
      "score": "4"
  },
  "q": {
      "text": "Disagree",
      "score": "2"
  },
  "q": {
      "text": "StronglyDisagree",
      "score": "1"
  },
  "q": {
      "text": "Agree",
      "score": "3"
  },
  "q": {
      "text": "Agree",
      "score": "3"
  }
}
```

Using:

```
temp_answers::json->>'q';
```

only returns one of the values from the set of answers.

I was really wanting to be able to use a json function to grab all the scores but it's looking like I won't be able to.
Does anyone have any good ideas or a functions I am missing?

Postgres version 9.4

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a different approach and flattening your json to your required rows.

Assuming a `quiz` table with `id` and json `answers` columns:

```
WITH scores AS (
  SELECT
    q.id, a.key AS question, (a.value ->> 'score')::INT AS score FROM quiz q
    JOIN json_each(q.answers) a ON TRUE 
)
SELECT *
FROM scores;
```

If you need to restrict the keys to only those starting with "q" then join `ON a.key LIKE 'q%'`.

Comment: I had to loop through a bunch of different rows and perform different actions based on the value of a column so I ended up going with a different regex:   `FOR question IN
  SELECT regexp_matches(row.answers, 'q[0-9]+', 'g') as q_text
  LOOP
  answer = row.answers::json->>question.q_text[1];
  answer = answer::json->>'score';

  END LOOP;` .  Thanks for the suggestion though!